# How do I add a function and href to javascript single onclick function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, url, onclick

I want to add a javascript variable value next to a URL. I'll explain with the code below.

First I want a name in the URL, I used the below code to do that,

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  var name = urlParams.get('name');
</script>
```

And then I want to preview the variable's value, like the following:

```html
<script>
   document.write(name);
</script>
```

Then I want to get the user name as input. for that, I used a prompt.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
  function getYourName() {
    name=prompt("Enter you name here");
  }  
</script>
```

Then I want to share a web URL with the user name as 'get' method,

```html
<a target="blank" href="#" onclick="getYourName(); this.href='whatsapp://send?text=Click here to see magic_ ->https://*sample*.com'+'?name='+**name**;"  data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share</a>
```

But It's not working!
I want to generate the link as

```
> Click here to see magic_ -> https://sample.com?name=USER_ENTERED_NAME
```

How can I integrate the value of the variable into the link?

Comment: If the name is in the URL parameter, why are you prompting for it?

Comment: I'll save you weeks of time, inline script will mess with a lot of HTTPS compliant sites. You should in your allowed script insert a event listener on touch down. And perform actions there.

Comment: @blanknamefornow I've never heard of that before. Inline JS has been common for ages, and millions of sites would break if a popular browser stopped supporting it.

Comment: @Barmar It's not created to show the same name, When someone(person1) share that link with his/her(person1) name,  the page will show the (person1) name, then the second person can share the link with his/her (person2)name. I think you can understand my isssue.

Comment: It has to do with the Content Security Policies site admins choose to apply and it's fully warranted if you're wanting HSTS and fully compliance. We've done it loads during HTTP, and you can allow it but by default when the helmet is army-grade, nu-uhh... no in-line scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the link inside your function getYourName()

```
function getYourName() {
    const name=prompt("Enter you name here");
    location.href = "https://sample.com?name="+name;
}
```

You have to cancel your href attribute inside onclick.

Comment: Thank you very much @stefino76  It's working. 